# User defined functions with LessCSS?

Tags: less

I have just recently gotten into LessCSS and I am running into what I feel is major limitation and I was wondering if there was a way to do this?? I want to say I read somewhere that Sass allows for user defined functions but will LessCSS do the same?

What I'm wanting to do:

```
@fs: 16;

// either return the value
.s(@t,@s,@u) {
    // return @t/@s*@u;
}
#elem {
    margin-top: .s(30,@fs,1em);
    width: .s(900,@fs,1em);
    .child {
        width: .s(100,900,100%);
    }
}

// or have a property argument
.s(@t,@s,@u,@p) {
    @{p}: @t/@s*@u;
}
#elem {
    .s(30,@fs,1em,margin-top);
    .s(900,@fs,1em,width);
    .child {
        .s(100,900,100%,width);
    }
}
```

The only way I can figure it out, but it is very limited because I have to have multiple mixins:

```
.s(@t,@s,@u,@p) when (@p = margin-top) { margin-top: @t/@s*@u; }
// margin[-top|-right|-bottom|-left]
// padding[-top|-right|-bottom|-left]
.s(@t,@s,@u,@p) when (@p = width) { width: @t/@s*@u; }
.s(@t,@s,@u,@p) when (@p = height) { height: @t/@s*@u; }
```

I know I can always modify the less.js file to add a spacing function like the built-in `round()` or `ceil()` function. But, that kills the option of compiling the .less files for production using LessPHP, Crunch, SimpLess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no property argument: you must write it down.

That is, a function will return a calculated value or instruction(s) (property/ies and calculated values).

There aren't thousands of properties in CSS, it's not a CMS with hundreds of classes and functions, so your list won't be as long as you can imagine. You should use other CSS preprocessors or a backend language to generate your CSS if you want to do such complicated things. Or better keep it simple.
That said, [lessphp allows for user functions](http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#custom_functions):

> lessphp has a simple extension interface where you can implement user functions that will be exposed in LESS code during the compile. They can be a little tricky though because you need to work with the lessphp type system.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Instead of having to rely on lessphp, I have decided to just make `dimensions.less` and import it. The file contains `.width()` `.padding()` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you also can easily add custom functions to the default Less compiler, which enable you to use the client side `less.js` compiler for testing and the command line `lessc` compiler for production.

**For Less 1.x**

1. Download and unzip the source from github at: https://github.com/less/less.js/releases/latest
2. Run `npm install`
3. Open the `lib/functions.js` file
4. Add your custom function (`returncenter()` in this example) inside the `tree.functions` object, for instance as follows:

   ```
   tree.functions = {
   returncenter: function() {
   return new(tree.Anonymous)('center');
   },
   //original function below
   }
   ```
5. Run `grunt dist`

After the preceding step you can include dist/less-1.x.x/js in your HTML or compile your Less code with the `dist/lessc` compiler.

**For Less 2.x**

1. Download and unzip the source from github at: https://github.com/less/less.js/archive/master.zip
2. Run `npm install`
3. Create a file caleld `lib/less/functions/custom.js` and write down the following content into it:

   ```
   var Anonymous = require("../tree/anonymous"),
       functionRegistry = require("./function-registry");

   functionRegistry.addMultiple({
   returncenter: function() {
   return new(Anonymous)('center');
   }
   });
   ```
4. Open the `lib/less/function/index.js` file and append `require("./custom");` to the list of register functions, just before `return functions;`
5. Run `grunt dist`

Now you can use the following Less code:

```
selector {
property: returncenter();    
}
```

The preceding Less code will compile into the following CSS code:

```
selector {
property: center;    
}
```

Comment: It's a nightmare that modifying the original library because others have to use the same modified codes to get things work.