# How to compute the cubehelix color scheme in Less.js?

Tags: less, cielab

I want to compute the cubehelix color scheme in Less so I can tweak some variables. I believe this necessitates CIE L*a*b color system. I ran across Chroma.js which seems like it would work for computing colors, but now I'd like to integrate this into Less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mike Bostock](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/) has implemented and extended cubehelix in JavaScript as a [plugin](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/cubehelix) for the D3.js visualisation library (see [examples](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/11415064)).

You can use the code of Bostock's plugin to write a [custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26224903/1596547) for Less.

1. Download and unzip the source from github at: https://github.com/less/less.js/archive/master.zip
2. Run `npm install`
3. Create a file called `lib/less/functions/cubehelix.js` and write down the following content into it:

   ```
   var Color = require("../tree/color"),
   functionRegistry = require("./function-registry");

   function d3_interpolate(y) {
   return function(a, b) {
         a = a.toHSL();
         b = b.toHSL();
         var radians = Math.PI / 180;
         var ah = (a.h + 120) * radians,
             bh = (b.h + 120) * radians - ah,
             as = a.s,
             bs = b.s - as,
             al = a.l,
             bl = b.l - al;

         if (isNaN(bs)) bs = 0, as = isNaN(as) ? b.s : as;
         if (isNaN(bh)) bh = 0, ah = isNaN(ah) ? b.h : ah;

         return function(t) {
           var h = ah + bh * t,
               l = Math.pow(al + bl * t, y),
               a = (as + bs * t) * l * (1 - l),
               cosh = Math.cos(h),
               sinh = Math.sin(h);
           return "#"
               + hex(l + a * (-0.14861 * cosh + 1.78277 * sinh))
               + hex(l + a * (-0.29227 * cosh - 0.90649 * sinh))
               + hex(l + a * (+1.97294 * cosh));
         };
       };
     }

   function hex(v) {
       var s = (v = v <= 0 ? 0 : v >= 1 ? 255 : v * 255 | 0).toString(16);
       return v < 0x10 ? "0" + s : s;
   }

   functionRegistry.addMultiple({
   cubehelix: function(y,a,b,t) {
   return new Color(d3_interpolate(y.value)(a,b)(t.value).slice(1),1);
   }   
   });
   ```
4. Open the `lib/less/function/index.js` file and append `require("./cubehelix");` to the list of register functions, just before `return functions;`
5. Run `grunt dist` (to create a new version of less.js)

Now the following Less code:

```
p{color: cubehelix(1,red,blue,1);}
p{color: cubehelix(1,red,blue,0.5);}
p{color: cubehelix(1, hsl(300,50%,0%), hsl(-240,50%,100%), 0.3);}
```

outputs:

```
p {
  color: #766cfd;
}
p {
  color: #21ba40;
}
p {
  color: #4c4c4c;
}
```